Prettier не форматирует кавычки в .html файле
у меня есть конфиг prettier в проекте:
{
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "bracketSameLine": true,
    "semi": true,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "printWidth": 100,
    "requireConfig": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "endOfLine": "lf",
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "singleAttributePerLine": true,
    "jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "useTabs": false,
    "plugins": ["@prettier/plugin-pug", "prettier-plugin-css-order"]
}

Как видно в конфиге указан "singleQuote": true и действительно, например в файлах .pug, кавычки заменяются на одинарные. Здорово! Это то что и хотел.
Но вот засада, почему-то, кавычки в html файлах не меняются на одинарные и это мой вопрос - ПОЧЕМУ ТАК? =((
Можно было бы подумать, что мой prettier не реагирует на html файлы но нет, в этом же конфиге есть настройка "bracketSameLine": true и она прекрасно работает в html если её менять на true или false.
Я явно где-то прокололся, но где? =))
Заранее большое спасибо!

Никто не использует одинарные кавычки в html. Полагаю, они и не реализовывали это. Даже для jxs отдельная строка конфига. Вот и на html обычная тоже не распространяется.

Что ж, кажется это действительно не баг а фича, согласно тому что я прочитал вот тут:
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5828?fbclid=IwZXh0bgNhZW0CMTAAAR1qUdZurR6GRLhdq-ydeVgtpop7ED11Jf1PJT8EU3ClXL-JnprayzjSF7s_aem_ATLS6rRoufio5-ssAO7eLipj49IslqApo4iUoL5YnsdOPe5SA2I0OVK78Taas6JGUavMNQI3xfF2lKYnFnsQH508
